# SSH agent GitHub private repo

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-agent

I am using SSH agent forwarding when connecting to server:

```
ssh -A my_server
```

Then I check agent is working in server:

```
echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
/tmp/ssh-IeuME30578/agent.30578
```

Then I try to test GitHub authentication from server:

```
ssh -T my_server
juan@myserver's password:
```

`my_server` is an alias defined in my local `~/.ssh/config`.

Why a password is asked in server?, if when I run in local:

```
ssh -T my_server
```

I get:

```
Hi juan! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

## Update

I have found that in server, aliases in my local ssh config are not available:

```
ssh my_alias
ssh: Could not resolve hostname awe: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```